# different pointer values from the same objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having a quite strange behaviour and I'd like to know what am I missing.

**I have a `Bus` object**, that represents a graph node.

**I have a `Branch` object** that represents a graph edge.

Then **I have a `Circuit` object** to host buses and branches.

The `Circuit` object has a function `addBus` that creates a `Bus` object, stores a copy in a vector and returns the pointer to the `Bus` object in the vector.

Those pointers are used by the branches to "remember" to which two nodes it is connected. See the main function in the code.

In the `Circuit`, the function `compile_all`, will create a dictionary with pointers to the `Bus` instances in the buses vector, and their corresponding vector index. This allows me number both buses and branches and build adjacency matrices, etc. that will be used in circuit matrix calculations.

**The problem is that, the pointers to the `Bus` instances I am getting from the `addBus` function and the ones I get when I loop the buses vector again in the `compile_all` function are different.**

The pointer values when I insert the objects in the vector:

```
ptr: 0x555d54bfc0d0
ptr: 0x555d54bfc268
ptr: 0x555d54bfc4d0
ptr: 0x555d54bfc598
ptr: 0x555d54bfc990
ptr: 0x555d54bfca58
```

the pointer values, when I loop the vector in the compile_all function:

```
set: 0x55b59aafd670
set: 0x55b59aafd738
set: 0x55b59aafd800
set: 0x55b59aafd8c8
set: 0x55b59aafd990
set: 0x55b59aafda58
```

**I don't see why are those different, since the objects that they point at are the same.**

```
/**
 * Bus bar
 */
template <int n_phase> class Bus{


public:

    string name;

    /**
     * @brief Bus constructor
     */
    Bus(string name_){
        name = name_;
    }
};


/**
 * General pi-model branch element
 */
template <int n_phase> class Branch{


public:


    /**
     * @brief Node connection 1
     */
    Bus<n_phase> * from;

    /**
     * @brief Node connection 2
     */
    Bus<n_phase> * to;


    /**
     * @brief Branch
     * @param z0_
     * @param z1_
     */
    Branch(Bus<n_phase> * from_, Bus<n_phase> * to_){
        from = from_;
    to = to_;
    }
};

/**
 * general single-island circuit model.
 */
template <int n_phase> class Circuit{


private:

    std::vector<Bus<n_phase>> buses;

    std::vector<Branch<n_phase>> branches;

    std::map<Bus<n_phase>*, int> bus_dict;

public:

    /**
     * @brief Circuit
     */
    Circuit(){
    }


    /**
     * @brief Add a bus to the circuit
     * @return poiter to the added bus object
     */
    Bus<n_phase>* addBus(string name_){
        buses.push_back(Bus<n_phase>(name_));
        return &buses[buses.size()-1];
    }


    /**
     * @brief Add a branch to the circuit
     * @return pointer to the branch objects that has been added
     */
    Branch<n_phase>* addBranch(Bus<n_phase>* bf, Bus<n_phase>* bt){

        branches.push_back(Branch<n_phase>(bf, bt));

        return &branches.back();
    }


    /**
     * @brief compile all the data into matrices for calculation
     */
    void compile_all(){

        // initialize variables
        int n = buses.size();
        int m = branches.size();
        int f, t;

        // initialize structures
        bus_dict.clear();

        // loop through the nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            // create entry in the bus_dict dictionary
            bus_dict[&buses[i]] = i;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        // loop through the branches
        for (int i = 0; i < m ; i++){

            f = bus_dict[branches[i].from];
            t = bus_dict[branches[i].to];

            // add connectivity relation
            connectivity.set_relation(f, t, i);
        }

    }


};



void main(){

    cout << "Test Engine 1" << endl;

    const int phases = 3;

    Circuit<phases> circuit;

    Bus<phases>* b0 = circuit.addBus("B0");
    Bus<phases>* b1 = circuit.addBus("B1");
    Bus<phases>* b2 = circuit.addBus("B2");
    Bus<phases>* b3 = circuit.addBus("B3");
    Bus<phases>* b4 = circuit.addBus("B4");
    Bus<phases>* b5 = circuit.addBus("B5");

    circuit.addBranch(b0, b1);
    circuit.addBranch(b0, b2);
    circuit.addBranch(b2, b3);
    circuit.addBranch(b3, b5);
    circuit.addBranch(b2, b4);
    circuit.addBranch(b4, b5);

    circuit.compile_all();

};
```

Comment: You can't use the address of a element in a vector if you continue to insert objects.

Comment: I'm used to do this successfully in Java, Python and C#. How shall I proceed here to achieve unique object pointers?

Comment: A std::deque or a std::list should work

Comment: std::deque was the 1 to 1 replacement, so if you post the answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: As you continue to `push_back` elements the container may need to reallocate memory and move objects around. This invalidates all iterators and pointers to elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A std::deque or a std::list should work.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have just read that deque doe not guarantee the sequential storage of objects. Does that mean that the first object I insert might not be the index zero at some point?

Comment: No, that does mean that a deque is not one big chunk of memory like vector, but many smaller chunks. But if you insert at position 0 it will stay there.